# Network Failure at XMLHttpRequest in AWS uploadpart function for Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to implement multipart upload in AWS using Javascript SDK. What I understood was that first I have to create a initiate request, then upload the parts, and then give a complete request. I'm able to successfully create a request and upload the first part of file, but when I try to upload the second part, I always get following error:

```
{ "message": "Network Failure", "code": "NetworkingError", "time": "2016-11-04T08:55:46.056Z", "region": "us-east-1", "hostname": "bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com", "retryable": true }, NetworkingError: Network Failure at XMLHttpRequest. (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.6.15.min.js:34:12349)
```

I have implemented following code for it:

```
<head>
  <title>JavaScript SDK AWS</title>
    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.6.15.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <iframe id="myFrame" style="display:none"></iframe>


<!-- UPLOADING AN OBJECT INTO S3 -->

<input type="file" multiple id="file-chooser" /> <!-- file chooser to upload  a file --> 
<!--<input type="file" multiple id="file-chooser" /> --><!-- multiple file chooser to upload  a file --> 
<button id="initiate-request-button">Initiate request</button> <!-- button to create request for multiupload to s3 -->
<button id="upload-parts-button">Upload Part1 to S3</button> <!-- button to upload parts to s3 -->
<button id="upload-parts-button1">Upload Part2 to S3</button> <!-- button to upload parts to s3 -->
<button id="complete-parts-request-button">Complete multi part request </button> <!-- button to complete upload request to s3 -->
<div id="tempresults"></div>
<div id="tempresultsid"></div>
<div id="results"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
//USE THE HTTPGET FUNCTION HERE TO GET CREDENTIALS INSTEAD OF HARDCODING.   

var openIDToken = '{"AccessKeyId":access_key_id,"SecretAccessKey":secret_access_key}';


    //PARSE THE JSON OBJECT TO GET CREDENTIALS. 
    obj =  JSON.parse(openIDToken);
        var AccessKeyId = obj.AccessKeyId; //Get AccessID  
        var SecretAccessKey = obj.SecretAccessKey; //Get secret key for the user

        //set region to Whichever region is being used. 
        AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

        //set credentials to AWS
        AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: AccessKeyId,  
                           secretAccessKey: SecretAccessKey
                       });

    var s3BucketName = 'bucketname';
    var results = document.getElementById('results'); //get the results field. 
    var tempresults = document.getElementById('tempresults'); //get the results field. 
    var tempresultsid = document.getElementById('tempresultsid'); //get the results field. 
    results.innerHTML = ''; //set results to '' before trying anything. 
    var s3 = new AWS.S3({ params: {Bucket: s3BucketName} , httpOptions: {timeout: 20000000}});
    var fileChooser = document.getElementById('file-chooser'); //get the filechooser. 
    var uploadID= ''; //for uploadid of initial request
    var initiaterequestbutton = document.getElementById('initiate-request-button'); //get the upload button 

    initiaterequestbutton.addEventListener('click', function()  //add a event listener to the click button 
      {
      var file = fileChooser.files[0]; 

        results.innerHTML = ''; //set results to '' before trying anything. 
        tempresults.innerHTML = ''; //set results to '' before trying anything. 
        var params = {
          Bucket: s3BucketName, /* required */
          Key: file.name
        };
        s3.createMultipartUpload(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            results.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(err, null, 4)+', '+err.stack;
          } else {
            uploadID = JSON.stringify(data.UploadId, null, 4);
            tempresults.innerHTML = fileChooser.files[0];
            uploadID = uploadID.substring(1,uploadID.length-1);
            // results.innerHTML = uploadID.substring(1,uploadID.length-1);
          }
        });

    }, false);

      var uploadpartsbutton = document.getElementById('upload-parts-button'); //get the upload button 
      uploadpartsbutton.addEventListener('click', function()  //add a event listener to the click button 
      {
          var file = fileChooser.files[0]; 

          var params = {
            Bucket: s3BucketName, /* required */
            Key: file.name, /* required */
            PartNumber: 1, /* required */
            UploadId: uploadID, /* required */
            Body: file
          };
          var tempresultsid = document.getElementById('tempresultsid'); //get the results field. 
          tempresultsid.innerHTML = uploadID;
          s3.uploadPart(params, function(err, data) {
              if (err) {
              results.innerHTML += "**"+JSON.stringify(err, null, 4)+', '+err.stack;
            } else {
              results.innerHTML += "**"+JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
            }
          });
        }, false);

        var uploadpartsbutton1 = document.getElementById('upload-parts-button1'); //get the upload button 
        uploadpartsbutton1.addEventListener('click', function()  //add a event listener to the click button 
      {
          var file = fileChooser.files[0]; 

          var params = {
            Bucket: s3BucketName, /* required */
            Key: file.name, /* required */
            PartNumber: 2, /* required */
            UploadId: uploadID, /* required */
            Body: file
          };
          var tempresultsid = document.getElementById('tempresultsid'); //get the results field. 
          tempresultsid.innerHTML = uploadID;
          s3.uploadPart(params, function(err, data) {
              if (err) {
              results.innerHTML += "**"+JSON.stringify(err, null, 4)+', '+err.stack;
            } else {
              results.innerHTML += "**"+JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
            }
          });

          }, false);



</script> 
</body>

</html>
```

As it can be seen, the second file upload part is exactly the same as first art upload, albeit the part number.

I run the code in following way:

1. I first select the first part to be uploaded using file chooser.
2. Then I initiate the request using "Initiate request" button.
   The code runs fine and gives me the required uploadid.
3. Then I press "Upload Part1 to S3" to upload part1, which is already select in the filechooser. This code also runs fine and returns me etag.
4. The I select the second part in same file chooser, and press "Upload Part2 to S3". This is where I get the error. 
   Even in the network tab in browser console, it shows error as :

   **net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**

I don't understand why this is happening, as the same code works fine for first file(up.zip) and then then fails with the second one. Attached screenshot of browser console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue. All the parts need to have same file name, at least that's what  resolved this problem of mine.

Comment: Do you have adblock or ublock?

Comment: I do, but I had disabled it and tried in different browsers too. Keeping same name for different parts did the trick for Me.

Comment: I am facing same error. What do you mean by All the parts need to have same file name? I have given file reference same as you and its just one file. Can you please provide any guidance?